# DISTINCT keyword not working in mysql query

Tags: mysql, join

I have ran into a problem that my mysql query is not working as expected. I am joining 3 tables using `union` and from the result i want to ignore the repeating words. For that I have used `DISTINCT` keyword. But it is not working as expected.

My query is,

```
SELECT DISTINCT(catnam), sub2id 
FROM tbl_first_page_products f INNER JOIN subcategory_level2 s 
ON f.brand_id = s.sub2id 
WHERE f.title_cat = 'men' 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT(catnam), sub2id 
FROM tbl_third_page_products f INNER JOIN subcategory_level2 s 
ON f.brand_id = s.sub2id 
WHERE f.title_cat = 'men' 
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT(catnam), sub2id 
FROM tbl_fourth_page_products f INNER JOIN subcategory_level2 s 
ON f.brand_id = s.sub2id 
WHERE f.title_cat = 'men'
```

And my result is,

```
catnam    sub2id
------    ------
Levi's      4
United      1
Reebok     130
Jack       18
Proline    77
Levi's     161
Arrow      284
```

In the above result `Levi's` is repeating. How to ignore this. I need only one `Levi's`. Is there any way to avoid this. I am stuck in here.

Comment: You can use a GROUPY BY, but then you will loose a sub2id. Is this sub2id important? Which one of the sub2id's do you need if you only want one?

Comment: how come Levi's 4 and Levi's     161 become same ? if you use mutitple column with different data it'll consider other column also

Comment: @etalon11 : `sub2id` not important

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi : not same, getting from two table.

Comment: if `sub2id` is not important then why are you selecting it. Just remove it and you will get the desired result.

Comment: @SMA : not important means, the second repeating `Levis's` is not important.

Comment: Your table names and the use of UNION are a strong smell that the database design is less than optimal. If you are still in the early stages, I recommend you change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL DISTINCT with multiple columns

You can use the DISTINCT clause with more than one column. In this case, MySQL uses the combination of all columns to determine the uniqueness of the row in the result set.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx

if you want solve your problem, you can use group_concat() function then you group by catnam for all union queries :

```
SELECT name ,GROUP_CONCAT(id)  
FROM your_table
GROUP BY name ;
```

so your query can be:

```
SELECT distinct(catnam) as catnam, GROUP_CONCAT(sub2id )  
FROM tbl_first_page_products f INNER JOIN subcategory_level2 s 
ON f.brand_id = s.sub2id 
WHERE f.title_cat = 'men'
UNION 
SELECT distinct(catnam) as catnam, GROUP_CONCAT(sub2id )
FROM tbl_third_page_products f INNER JOIN subcategory_level2 s 
ON f.brand_id = s.sub2id 
WHERE f.title_cat = 'men' 
UNION 
SELECT distinct(catnam) as catnam, GROUP_CONCAT(sub2id ) 
FROM tbl_fourth_page_products f INNER JOIN subcategory_level2 s 
ON f.brand_id = s.sub2id 
WHERE f.title_cat = 'men'
group by catnam
```

Comment: same result repeating

Answer (score 2):

I'd try:

```
SELECT n, GROUP_CONCAT(sub2id )
FROM
(
SELECT catnam n, sub2id 
...
UNION
SELECT catnam, sub2id
...
)
GROUP BY n
```

Comment: To ensure correct/expected behavior, I'd make it `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT sub2id)` or explicitly use `UNION DISTINCT` instead of `UNION` since older versions of MySQL server incorrectly interpreted an unqualified `UNION` as meaning `UNION ALL`.  Also, I think you'll need a table alias for the derived table, so `) xxx GROUP BY n` at the end, where `xxx` is an arbitrary name for the derived table.